# OR Condition in Query String SharePoint 2013

Tags: list-view, filter, url

I use query string to filter SharePoint View

```
=FilterField1TestField-FilterValue1TestValue-FilterField2AnotherTestField-FilterValue2AnotherTestValue.
```

The above string performs AND operation between Field1 and Field2

Is there a way to perform OR condition in query string to filter the View?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a pretty good write-up of how these work: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/filtering-and-sorting-sharepoint-list-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use an OR in URL filters. It is possible to apply a filter to a field that can take multiple values. Example.

```
http://server/site/Lists/mylist/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=field1&FilterMultiValue=value1;value2
```

The alternative is to try to create a calculated field with a more complex condition and then filter by that field.

Answer (score 0):

The query string filter works same as how the List View filter works.

Your best option is to edit the list view's CAML query and handle this use case.