# Filter a SharePoint list by URL parameters and OR combining filters

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, filter

my goal is to create a URL that filters a SharePoint list with two filters that are logical OR combined.

What I have so far is:

```
AllItems.aspx/?
 useFiltersInViewXml=1
 &FilterFields1=Data1
 &FilterValues1=123
 &FilterTypes1=Text
 &FilterOp1=In
 &FilterFields2=Data2
 &FilterValues2=321
 &FilterTypes2=Text
 &FilterOp2=In
```

But that AND combines the two filters. Is it possible to OR combine them?

Comment: Check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191945/or-condition-in-query-string-sharepoint-2013/. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap-MVP,
thank you, I see it is not possible without creating an additional calculated field.

Comment: Yes, you cannot add OR conditions based on URL query string parameters.

Comment: I have added an answer below with some explanation and above link for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, No.

You cannot add `OR` conditions for SharePoint list view filters based on URL query string parameters.

However, if you are trying to filter list view based on multiple selection allowed columns (like Choice column), you can use filters like below based on URL query string parameters:

```
<site-url>/lists/mylist/AllItems.aspx?FilterFields1=Data1&FilterValues1=Value1;#Value2&FilterTypes1=MultiChoice
```

For other workarounds, check similar thread at: [OR Condition in Query String SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191945/or-condition-in-query-string-sharepoint-2013/)